# C++ push to 3 different vectors with one shared method

Tags: c++

I'm pretty new to C++, and I'm finding the whole concept of pointers, double pointers and references some-what confusing.

I am writing an object loader for an assignment and have came to the part where I want to optimise/modularise my solution.

Right now I have 3 vectors which contain information regarding the objects texture coords, faces and normals. Instead of having an operation for each, I wish to neaten my codebase by introducing a method to handle pushing to the following vectors.

```
std::vector<XMFLOAT3> vert_texture_coord;
std::vector<XMFLOAT3> vert_normals;
std::vector<XMFLOAT3> vert_position;
```

Currently I write to them like this:

```
vert_text_coord.push_back(XMFLOAT3(vert_x, vert_y, vert_z));
```

But to modularise I have written a method:

```
push_to_vector(float x, float y, float z, *vector)
{
    // push code here
}
```

Calling it like this

```
push_to_vector(vert_x, vert_y, vert_z, &vert_text_coord);
```

Am I right to be passing the reference of `vert_text_coord` to the pointer parameter `*vector` in my `push_to_vector` method, or am I doing this wrong?  Finally would it also make sense to have parameters `vert_x, vert_y, vert_z` as references too or have I completely misunderstood the concept of `&`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are using C++11 you can just use `vert_texture_coord.emplace_back(vert_x, vert_y, vert_z)`. There is no need for an extra function here.

Comment: @cdhowie yes I am using C++ 11, interesting solution.  I do need to really get my head around using pointers and references efficiently though! So daunting coming from a Java background :P

Comment: "*But to optimise I have written a method[...]*" Optimize what? The speed? If so, that's not going to optimize speed at all.

Comment: @Cornstalks I should have said modularise, my bad!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, I think you are asking the wrong question here. Yes, you can perfectly well pass a pointer/reference to a function that pushes an `XMFLOAT3` to the end of a vector, the working code would be

```
//function signature:
push_to_vector(std::vector<XMFLOAT3>* v, float x, float y, float z);

//call:
push_to_vector(&ver_normals, x, y, z);
```

or using references

```
//function signature:
push_to_vector(std::vector<XMFLOAT3>& v, float x, float y, float z);

//call:
push_to_vector(ver_normals, x, y, z);
```

However, as I said, that answers the wrong question. The right question would be: Is the idea of a `push_to_vector()` function a good one? And I believe, it is not. The reason is, that a `push_to_vector()` function is the wrong abstraction. Code that uses your three vectors will never want to abstract from which vector it uses, it will want to abstract from the fact that it uses a vector.

It is bad to have too long functions, but it is also bad to have tons of one-line functions like a `push_to_vector()` function. Each function should strive to have a sufficiently large difference in abstraction level between what it uses and what it provides. If that is not the case, you'll get lost in the deep call hierarchies that you will create.

(It is no accident, that the [International Obfuscated C Code Contest](http://www.ioccc.org/) has winning entries that either fuse everything into one function, or that have something like 50 functions, each of which are only a few characters long. Either method is equally efficient at obfuscating the code.)

---

Here is my two cents to the question whether it is better to use pointers or references:

Consider the following five functions:

```
void foo(int x);
void bar(int& x);
void baz(int* x);
void bim(const int& x);
void bam(const int* x);
```

and their corresponding calls:

```
int var = 7;
foo(var);    //may not change var
bar(var);    //may change var
baz(&var);   //may change var
bim(var);    //may not change var
bam(&var);   //may not change var
```

The first call is the normal case in C++, and it cannot change its argument as it uses pass by value. I believe it is a really good idea, if you can see directly at the call whether the call will change its argument. Thus I restrict myself to either use pass by value, pass by pointer, or pass by `const` reference, i. e. these three variants:

```
foo(var);    //may not change var
baz(&var);   //may change var, visible by the take-address operator
bim(var);    //may not change var, pass by value semantics optimized via a const reference
```

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts, very interesting post.  Looks like I've a lot to learn with c++

Answer (score 1):

`&` takes the address of the object, so when you write `&vert_text_coord` you get a `vector*`

To pass by reference, you need to have the reference parameter on the function.

```
push_to_vector(float x, float y, float z, vector& vec)
{
   vec.push_back(x,y,z);
}
```

You can then call the function like normal.

```
push_to_vector(vert_x, vert_y, vert_z, vert_text_coord);
```

Answer (score 1):

So far it looks like you have the right idea.

A correction: a pointer parameter in a function looks like `T*`, not `*T`. So your `push_to_vector` fucntion would be like:

`push_to_vector(float x, float y, float z, std::vector<XMFLOAT3>* v)`

Also, unless you plan on changing x, y, and z, there is no need to pass them by reference.

EDIT:
As cocarin's answer says, passing by reference here is really the right way to do it.

Also as a side note, this sounds like it might be a good idea to wrap all of your vectors into a class. That way you don't have to be throwing these vectors around in functions a lot.

Comment: ahh yes how did I forget to assign a type to vector, my bad - looks like I understood after all, thank-you! :)

Answer (score 1):

Learn to declare function parameters correctly.
As your function imitates method push_back that is written like

```
vert_text_coord.push_back(XMFLOAT3(vert_x, vert_y, vert_z));
```

then the first parameter should be reference to vector. For example

```
void push_to_vector( std::vector<XMFLOAT3> &, float, float, float );
```

In this case you can for example declare some parameters as having default arguments. For example

```
void push_to_vector( std::vector<XMFLOAT3> &, float = 0.0f, float = 0.0f, float = 0.0f );
```

And the function can be called like

```
push_to_vector( vert_text_coord, vert_x, vert_y, vert_z );
```

Or if you will declare some default arguments then like

```
push_to_vector( vert_text_coord );
```

You even can change default arguments of the function by means of redeclaring the function in a given (for example block) scope.

Also there is no sense to declare parameters of type float as references.

You could use a default argument for the last parameter as a mark that inside the function there should be used only two parameters.

```
void push_to_vector( std::vector<XMFLOAT3> &, float, float, float = 0.0f );
```

The function could be called either like

```
push_to_vector( vert_text_coord, vert_x, vert_y, vert_z );
```

or

```
push_to_vector( vert_text_coord, vert_x, vert_y );
```

In the last case vert_z woul be equal to 0.0f (or some other value) that would mean that the function itself should supply a required value.

Comment: Hmmm, so say I had another vector which was only an XMFLOAT2 (in the case I was using u,v coords and not u,v,w for textures), could I write another method with the same name to handle this? Or would I be able to modify the initial method to handle it

Comment: @Alex In this case that to avoid ambiguity the first function should not have default arguments. In this case you can overload the function for two float parameters. Or you could use the same function but define the third parameter with default argument that will mean that the parameter shall not be used in the function body.

Comment: Could you possibly extend your answer to show an example? Sounds like thats the sort of solution I need to go for